# How does PSScriptRoot inside Dot-Sourced file work?

Tags: powershell, relative-path, dot-source

Suppose I have 2 files, `A.ps1` and `B.ps1`, in this directory structure:

```
--  root
 |
 |-- A.ps1
 |
 |--  subfolder
   |
   |-- B.ps1
```

**A.ps1:**

```
Write-Host $PSScriptRoot
```

**B.ps1:**

```
. "\root\A.ps1"
```

Now, taking [this fact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579650/3705191) into account:

> Dot sourcing takes the script you've specified and immediately executes it as though it had been at that spot in your original script

##### **THE PROBLEM:** If I were to run `B.ps1`, I would *expect* the result to be `\root\subfolder`, but it's `\root`, why??

If `A.ps1` is dot-sourced into `B.ps1`, shouldn't the contents of script `A.ps1` run *as if* they were written directly inside of `B.ps1`? Meaning, shouldn't `$PSScriptRoot` run as if it was called from `B.ps1`, and thus evaluate to `\root\subfolder`? I've even tested this by wrapping `A.ps1` in a function and calling that function in `B.ps1` *after* dot-sourcing. Still yields the same result..

How does dot-sourcing really work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667238/how-can-i-get-the-file-system-location-of-a-powershell-script

Comment: _How does dot-sourcing really work?_, [the docs are pretty clear on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-): Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current scope, overriding existing ones. `$PSScriptRoot` of `A.ps1` is `\root`, dot sourcing does not change that fact.

Comment: Also, the docs for ```$PSScriptRoot``` have this to say: “Contains the full path of the **executing** script's parent directory.” (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psscriptroot). Even though ```A.ps1``` is executing in ```B.ps1```’s scope, it’s still ```A.ps1``` **executing**, so ```$PSScriptRoot``` contains ```A.ps1```’s parent folder path.

Answer (score 7):

As commenters noted, `$PSScriptRoot` is independent of scope. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psscriptroot) (emphasis mine):

> $PSScriptRoot
> Contains the full path of the **executing** script's parent directory.

Dot-Sourcing doesn't literally "include" the script at the spot (contrary to the `#include` directive of C++, for instance), PowerShell still knows it is running a different script. The only thing that is different compared to *calling* the script (explicitly using the call operator `&` or running the script by entering its path), is the [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#using-dot-source-notation-with-scope).

There is a way to get the `$PSScriptRoot` of the calling script though. Turn the script to be dot-sourced into an [advanced function cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) by using the `CmdletBinding()` and/or the `Parameter()` attribute. This makes the automatic variable [`$PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pscmdlet) available, which gives you (amongst other things), the `$PSScriptRoot` of the invoking script.

**A.ps1**

```sh
# CmdletBinding is an attribute of param(), so that is required as well
[CmdletBinding()] param()

$PSScriptRoot                         # Outputs directory that contains A.ps1
$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot   # Outputs directory of the invoking script
```

Comment: Nice :-). As a personal style, I only really use dot-sourcing to define functions, and then call those functions in my main script - I don’t like the idea of a dot-sourced script actually executing code with side effects as it makes it harder to remember what is happening where (and once you get more than a handful of functions, turn it into a module)…

Comment: @mclayton Agreed, side effects can be a nightmare. Another valid usecase is dot-sourcing of script blocks. In many cases I want the script block to be able to easily modify surrounding variables, so I dot-source it.